# local artifactory golang proxy and checksum verification

Tags: artifactory

When getting go modules using a local artifactory go proxy "go get" fails when doing module checksum verification.

At work we can't do downloads directly from internet but must go through a local proxy based on artifactory. I have specified GOPROXY (GOPROXY=https://repo.mycompany.se/artifactory/api/go/gocenter) to a proxy setup in our local artifactory. When running "go get" the download goes ok what I can see but the checksum verification fails as go try to use sum.golang.org directly instead of getting the checksum through the proxy.

```
C:\Users\x\go\src\hello2>go get rsc.io/quote@v1.5.2
go: finding rsc.io v1.5.2
go: downloading rsc.io/quote v1.5.2
verifying rsc.io/quote@v1.5.2: rsc.io/quote@v1.5.2: Get https://sum.golang.org/lookup/rsc.io/quote@v1.5.2: dial tcp: lookup sum.golang.org: no such host

C:\Users\x\go\src\hello2>
```

Do artifactory support getting the checksum through the local proxy and if so how do you set it up. I have read a blog post about support when using gocenter directly but I can't find any information when using artifactory.

I'm using go 1.13 and we are using artifactory 6.12.2.

Answer (score 0):

Artifactory 6.12.2 when used as golang proxy, currently does not support checksum verification when there is no access to sum.golang.org. A feature request RTFACT-20405 (Artifactory to support go client checksum verification when sum.golang.org is not accessible).

In the meantime, refer to 'go help module-private' and [documentation](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Module_authentication_failures) on using GONOSUMDB environment variables.  An excerpt taken from the [1](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Module_authentication_failures) -

"If GOSUMDB is set to "off", or if "go get" is invoked with the -insecure flag, the checksum database is not consulted, and all unrecognized modules are accepted, at the cost of giving up the security guarantee of verified repeatable downloads for all modules. A better way to bypass the checksum database for specific modules is to use the GOPRIVATE or GONOSUMDB environment variables. See 'go help module-private' for details"

Answer (score 0):

Artifactory 6.16 has gosumdb support - https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Release+Notes